# Zero value replace by average value by catagory

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a table:

```
Product  Customer  Value
x        A         10
y        A         20
x        B         0
x        C         12
y        C         24
x        D         15
y        D         30
```

And like to the zero value in a power BI visualization table as average of Product category.
Expected Output:

```
Product  Customer  Value
x        A         10
y        A         20
x        B         12.33
x        C         12
y        C         24
x        D         15
y        D         30
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculated Column:

```
NewValue = 
  IF(
    [Value] <> 0,
    [Value],
    CALCULATE( AVERAGE(Table[Value]), ALLEXCEPT(Table, Table[Product]), Table[Value] <> 0 )
  )
```